# # sudo dd bs=512 count=1 if=/dev/sda 2>/dev/null | strings

Tags: fedora

## sudo dd bs=512 count=1 if=/dev/sda 2>/dev/null | strings

t&fh
TCPAu2
r,fh
fSfSfUfh
Invalid partition table
Error loading operating system
Missing operating system
/`8:
what does this mean

Answer (score 1):

This means that piping content of your `MBR` to `strings` is commonly useless and makes no sense . . .

Comment: I'd say it means that users should not play with potions and spells [without understanding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sorcerer%27s_Apprentice)